# What is "Cannot verify Server identity" in iOS

Tags: iphone, .net, ios, objective-c

I am calling .net service through my iPhone app, its working fine in iPhone and iPad, i get result and response. but when i try to run same app in iPhone5 version 6.1.4, i got error exception "Cannot verify Server identity". why this error occurred. please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

Just some food for thought. If you are using NSURLConnection have you implemented the following.

```
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace{

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

}
```

Sounds like some authentication issue, Otherwise it could also potentially be your server's certificates is having issues.